# Processing String forrmat doesn't add zeros

Tags: string, processing

SO it really should be very simple

```
float x =0;
for (int i=0;x<=100;i++){
print(String.format("%03.2f%n", x));
x+=10;
}
```

this is my current code and it should print
000,00
010,00
020,00
030,00
040,00
...
but it misses the 0 in the beginning
it only prints
0,00
10,00
20,00
...

Pretty sure the solution is simple but i just can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify which programming language you use. But sprintf is similar in many languages.

You're formatting a float. With a float, the first digit indicates the total number of positions for your string, *including the decimal separator*, and the second is the number of digits after the decimal separator. In your case, you specify three digits in total, of which two after the decimal separator. This is why you see `0,00`, `10.00`. Please note your formatter expands to 4 characters if it does not fit in the format you specified!

So you'll want to use the format `"%06.2f%n"`

I'll use `perl` to show you how it would work for me:

```
$ perl -E 'say sprintf("%06.2f", 20)'
020.00
```

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah that makes sense. I thought it would be something easy but I just can't see it. I appreciate the help.
And in terms of the program, i added a tag for processing, should I state the Program otherwise?
Asking for future problems

Comment: You write "I can't see it" but I think you have the solution now, right? You should write it like this: `print(String.format("%06.2f%n", x));` -- use a '6' instead of a '3', because that number is about the _total length_ of the resulting string, which is 6: 3 digits, a separator, and 2 digits.

My other remark was you added a tag for 'processing' but I wanted to understand which _programming language_ you use...!

Comment: Yeah i got it/understand it, it was just a spelling error by me, sorry.
The language is "processing", its like a rip off of java as far as i know

Comment: *"You do not specify which programming language you use. [...]"* - No. The programming language is well specified. It is [Processing](https://processing.org/). Read the tag-info [tag:processing] before you blame. (However it would be useful to add the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: @Leo Please upvote if the answer helped you. Also, accept it as the solution by clicking on the checkmark if it solved your problem. These actions are nice to the guy who spent time to help and will help future devs to find this information if they have a similar issue.

Comment: @Rabbid76 TIL about Processing. My bad!!